# I want to design automatically generated card in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I develop cards in react js that card automatically generated based on API data but that all card shows one below other and I want to design that card in row fashion. I try many ways to design that card in row way but it is not done. I try inline CSS, some react-bootstrap class. So please give me some suggestions about how I can design this card.

```
class App extends React.Component {

elements = [];
state = {
    data:[ null ]
};

getBikes = () => {
    try {
        return axios.get('URL')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    //this.elements=["one", "two", "three", "four"];
}

componentDidMount() {
    const breeds = this.getBikes()
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {

                console.log(response.data.message)
                var arr = (response.data.message);
                //var elements = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    console.log(arr[i].bikeId)
                    this.elements.push(<div>
                        <Cards value={arr[i]} />
                    </div>);
                }
                this.setState({ data: arr[0].bikeId })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

render() {

    console.log("printitng")
    //const array = [1,2];
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            <h1>{'This will always render'}</h1>
            {this.state && this.state.data &&

                this.state.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index} style={{ width: "300px" }}>
                        <Cards elements={this.elements} /> //pass your props value
                    </div>
                })

                // < div >
                // <Cards elements={this.elements} /> //pass your props value
                // </div>

            }
        </div>
    )


}
```

}

Comment: Use display : flex to the parent of cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   bikeId : null,
   data : []
  }
 }

 getBikes = () => {
  try {
      return axios.get('URL')
  } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
  }
 }
 componentDidMount() {
  const breeds = this.getBikes()
      .then(response => {
          if (response) {
              this.setState({ data: response.data.message, bikeId: response.data.message[0].bikeId })
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
      })
 }

 render() {
  return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {
            this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
                return <div key={index} style={{ width: "300px" }}>
                          <Cards value={item} />
                       </div>
            })
          }
      </div>
  )
 }
}
```

give parent class flex property then you can add as much child in a single row you can add.

Comment: Thanks, but using this its duplicate all the card based on array value & I want to show only that card which is based on API data

Comment: response.data.message length will decide how much react card will be generated and it's array so you must save it in your state, then inside render function you should map over it.

Comment: ok, I save API response in react state but I do not understand how I use react state as an array and map over it

Comment: Thank you very much iamnotbatma,  I was stuck in this problem since but now with your help, the problem gets solved.

Answer (score 1):

There's just one correction. You've pushed the elements of array with div which is a block element. You need push the elements with span or you can give class to the div and change from block to flex or inline block.

```
 componentDidMount() {
            const breeds = this.getBikes()
                .then(response => {
                    if (response) {
                console.log(response.data.message)
                var arr = (response.data.message);
                //var elements = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    console.log(arr[i].bikeId)
                   // Changed from div to span
                    this.elements.push(<span>
                                            <Cards value={arr[i]} />
                                       </span>);
                }
                this.setState({ data: arr[0].bikeId })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}

render() {

    console.log("printitng")

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'This will always render'}</h1>
            {this.state && this.state.data &&
                <div>
                    <Cards elements={this.elements} /> //pass your props value
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    )


}
```

}